# Dijkstra’s shortest-path algorithm what if there are paths with same distance?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

[image]

In this network Dijkstra’s shortest-path algorithm is used. 
The question is which path will A use to reach D because both are equal?

[image]

is that table missing?

Comment: Why does it matter (since they're equal)?

Comment: This is implementation detail. Either way is fine.

Comment: This is a homework, is A going to add both way to its table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your actual implementation and the way your input graph was described (e.g. edges can go in different order and this will have an impact on the result if there are many).

However, it's guaranteed that it will find *some* path which has optimal length.

Your table seems to be wrong at E and F vertices. The parent vertex for E is D (AB->BD->DE = 3 + 4 + 2 = 9), so is for F.

Comment: So, in this homework should I add both B and C as next router to reach D?

Comment: Indeed, how else would you know if C-D edge doesn't have a length of 1?

Comment: It asks for the shortest path from A to all network nodes by the way

Comment: If you know the *length* of the shortest path from A to D, then it doesn't matter which path you will actually use to go from D to other vertices in case that A->D->...->VERTEX has optimal length. Just pick that one eventual vertex from the queue and go on with it.

Comment: I am sorry but I am little confused so I have added my table on the question above. Now, in this table I should also add Destination D again and for that Next router will be C and cost 7, right?

Comment: Not necessarily, the single B at D is fine. Again, it doesn't matter which particular vertex you've chosen if there are many optimal paths.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation of the relaxation function. For example, the [algorithm described in the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) uses strictly a `less-than` comparison: `if alt < dist[v]` so in this case (and all the implementations I've seen) the shortest path from `A` to `D` is `A -> B -> D`.

Why? Because (`S` = settled nodes and `Q` = queue of nodes, a pair of distance, parent):

1. Start relaxing `A`, so you get the `S = {A:0}`  and `Q = {B:3,A C:5,A D:9,A}`
2. From `Q` select `B` and relax it. You get `S = {A:0 B:3,A}` and `Q = {C:(5,A) D:7,B E:10,B}`
3. From `Q` select `C` and relax it. You get `S = {A:0 B:3,A C:5,A}` and `Q = {D:7,B E:10,B}`.
4. From `Q` select `D` and you can finish the algorithm.

Note that in step 3, you don't need to change the parent of D because the new path is not better than the current path. If the relaxation algorithm uses a `less-than-or-equal` comparison, then the result will be different.